# how can I create multiple relationships using Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent-relationship

I have multiple tables and I want to make a relation between those and their pivot table, I'm using Laravel 9.

Database struture:

- networks

  - id
  - network_name
- teams

  - id
  - team_name
- tasks

  - id
  - task_name
- statuses

  - id
  - status_name
- task_team

  - id
  - task_id
  - team_id
- network_task_team

  - id
  - network_id
  - task_team_id
- network_status_task_team

  - id
  - network_task_team
  - status_id

I want to associate a Network to multiple Teams, associate a Team to multiple Tasks, and then each Network team task need to have multiple Statuses at the end.

I want to collect the lastest statuses from this task associate to a network and team.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The many-to-many relationships section of the Laravel documentation could be very helpful for you here [Laravel Eloquent Many-to-Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

For instance, the model of the network_status_task_team could be a pivot model between network_task_team and status tables. They are defined like this :

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class NetworkStatusTaskTeam extends Pivot
{
    //
}
```

You would then reference it in the Model classes of NetworkTaskTeam and Status.

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Status extends Model
{
    public function networkTaskTeams ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(NetworkTaskTeam::class)->using(NetworkStatusTaskTeam::class);
    }
}
```

And

```
<?php
             
 namespace App\Models;
             
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
             
 class NetworkTaskTeam extends Model
 {
      public function statuses()
      {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class)->using(NetworkStatusTaskTeam::class);
      }
  }
```

You would then apply the same logic to the other tables that you have.